# OV chipkart with 2 month subscription only

Tags: public-transport, amsterdam

Few of my friends are coming from India for a 2months internship purpose to Amsterdam, for which I need a OV chipkart/ GVB card with 2 months subscription only. Can you help me how I get  it? What documents are needed and what are the steps to apply?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What has your own research on this question revealed? [How to ask a good question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please specify what kind of a subscription do you have in mind. A monthly pass for GVB (Amsterdam buses and trams)? One of the NS (railway) discounts/passes?

Comment: The alternative for public transport in Amsterdam (most of the Netherlands) is cycling. It might work for them.

Answer (score 2):

The cards and the products you load on it are two separate things. Single-use tickets and tourist passes are basically a (disposable) card with a product already loaded on it. Unless they plan on using a debit card for their travels, you friends will therefore need a regular reusable OV-chipkaart. It will be cost €7.5 and be valid for about 5 years.

There are two options: anonymous card and personal card. The personal card effectively requires a local bank account, which is going to be an issue for your friends. You can get anonymous cards from vending machines, no paperwork necessary. The main drawback is that they cannot be used to load monthly subscriptions or tied to a bank account for automatic top-up.

Monthly subscriptions do exist but as I said they cannot be loaed without a personal card and I am not sure they will make sense as they can be pricey. I suspect that you may have something called the [student travel product](https://www.studentenreisproduct.nl/) and that's what you had in mind when writing the question. Unfortunately this kind of subscription won't be available to your friends since they are not enrolled in a year-long course at a Dutch institution of higher education. Their transportation will be (much) more expensive and you will have to study the details of all the travel products available from the [GVB](https://gvb.nl/) to figure out what they need.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, OP is already based in the Netherlands, thus presumably in possession of a Dutch bank account. Apart from that, the personal card only needs a Dutch address for correspondence and a Dutch telephone number, both of which OP could provide. So getting personal cards is not entirely impossible (although it might still not be worth it, hard to tell without further information on OP's goals). Subscriptions like NS Flex are cancellable monthly, so if OP is after train discounts or so, it is doable.

Comment: With the rollout of OVpay, an anonymous OV-chip makes fairly little sense these days (as long as you have a contactless payment card of any kind). At least in and around Amsterdam, there's nothing you can do with an anonymous OV-chip that you couldn't do with a bank card.

Comment: Also, I happen to own an anonymous OV-chip bought in June 2022 which is only valid till December 2025, so I'm not sure if the 5-year validity period still holds. Perhaps these days the validity is shorter as the OV-chipkaart is slated to be replaced with something new (something to do with OVpay, although I don't know any details).

Comment: @TooTea My assumption is that the OP wanted to assist these friends in getting their own card, not pay for their travels. I am not sure you can (or want) to associate a single bank account to the cards of a bunch of friends but that may indeed be possible. I did allude to OV-Pay in passing but since she said they are coming from India, I also suspect this might be impractical (e.g. because of currency exchange fees).

Comment: Re: Subscriptions, the main reasons I doubt they will be very useful is that (1) you need a personal OV chip card and (2) they are quite expensive. The question could obviously be more explicit about all that but as it mentions the GVB and an internship I was focusing on commute and leisure in the Amsterdam area, not so much on NS. Those subscriptions tend to be very pricey and I am not sure they can be cancelled monthly. But once those needs has been covered, sure, you could consider NS Flex (or use someone's *samenreiskorting*).

Comment: That's what led me to believe the OP mentioned subscriptions because she herself benefits from the student travel product (essentially free travel on all public transportation, only restriction is to choose between weekdays and weekends for train travel) and that was the subscription she wanted to get for her friends. But unfortunately that won't be possible if you only come for an internship, even if you are a student elsewhere and don't have much money. I don't see any discount you could use in that scenario.

Comment: Re: Anonymous OV-chip card, they have clearly become less necessary (which is a good thing) but they still have many uses: You can buy a reusable OV-chipcard in advance and preload it with some credit, reuse it for different visitors, even kids, all things you cannot do easily with a debit card.

Comment: Hi, regarding this" Monthly subscriptions do exist but as I said they cannot be loaed without a personal card and I am not sure they will make sense as they can be pricey."-- can you let me know the procedure to apply for it?

Comment: @KaveriChetia Depends on which one you are thinking about. You will first have to decide that, maybe with https://gvb-online.nl/flex-voordeel/ Then you can check the relevant provider's website, for the GVB you only need to show up with an ID and bank details in a GVB shop. But you have already received many comments regarding your question, please edit it to add some details instead of asking follow up questions in comments.